# NGINX end up merging SSE events from backend that is built with NodeJS & Express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server, server-sent-events

I'm running into an issue with Nginx when proxying Server-Sent Events (SSE) responses from my Express server.

When developing and testing the server locally from my `localhost`, it works super fine, but when I make it behind an NGINX server and deploy it to a DigitalOcean droplet (A virtual machine), it just throws a weird and breaking behavior which is merging every 2-3 SSE events into a single one.

#### **This is an example of the server code:**

```
// The method that generates SSE events.
function sseEvent(message, type, statusCode) {
  let types = ["warn", "info", "error", "result"];

  if (!types.includes(type)) {
    type = "info";
  }

  let obj = {
    message: message,
    type: type,
    date: new Date().toISOString(),
    statusCode: statusCode,
  };

  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}  

// The events I am sending in my server.
res.write(
      sseEvent(
        "Your Request data syntax is validated successfully, continuing..\n",
        "info",
        200
      )
    );

res.write(sseEvent("Validating the saved API key..", "info", 200));

// Something happens that takes time.

res.write(sseEvent("The saved API key is valid.", "info", 200));
```

if I hit call into the server port directly of that NodeJS server, it works fine from my client side, but since it needs to decode those JSON events when 2-3 are merged in somehow, it breaks the JSON decoder and so it breaks my whole app.

I suspect that NGINX has something that makes this weird behavior.

#### **I do have all the SSE headers from my server:**

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "X-Accel-Buffering": "no",
});
```

#### **And my nginx configuration:**

```
 location / {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   proxy_buffering off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   proxy_cache off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   chunked_transfer_encoding off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   proxy_set_header Connection '';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   proxy_set_header Cache-Control "no-cache";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding chunked;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   proxy_pass http://localhost:5559;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   proxy_read_timeout 3000s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 }
```

This is how the response are got from the client side:

```
// the first received event from that NGINX server, as you can see there is 2 merged in one event.
{"message":"Your Request data syntax is validated successfully, continuing..\n","type":"info","date":"2023-10-21T19:25:09.520Z","statusCode":200}{"message":"Validating the saved API key..","type":"info","date":"2023-10-21T19:25:09.520Z","statusCode":200}

// The second received event.
{"message":"The saved API key is valid.","type":"info","date":"2023-10-21T19:25:40.520Z","statusCode":200}
```

I hope someone can help clarify or just give me hints on it, if you need any extra information, please tell me.

#### **Things I suspect but I can't confirm**:

- Can this behavior be caused by the resources and power (CPU, RAM, storage) of the virtual machine?
- is this behavior expected from a spêcific version of NodeJS or express?
- is this just some bug from NGINX?

please, if you have anything on your mind let me know.

Thank you!